# Wiring illuminated momentary switch to breadboard

Tags: switches, datasheet, wiring

Software engineer fearlessly venturing into the deep, terrifying, murky waters of electronics here. And hoping everyone can take pitty on me (and be gentle) as I ask this simple question...

I'm looking to connect [this momentary switch](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/A22NZ-BNM-TWA/Z6671-ND/5603700) to a solderless breadboard but its datasheet seems to be a datasheet for a generic set of devices in the same family of switches that the manufacturer makes.

I'm just looking to understand what its wiring would look like. I have to *assume* (based on my heavily limited knowledge of electronics) that there are pins for: output signal (when the switch is pressed/closed), ground/`GND` and (because its illuminated) its internal LED...or would pressing the switch *also trigger* the internal LED to light up?

I guess my question is: is there information in its datasheet, or on the DigiKey page, that would tell me how to wire it up on a breadboard? Or is the datasheet junk? Or am I supposed to just have working knowledge with switches/electronics to begin with and the wiring of this device would be obvious to most EE folks? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the PN on the site is not corresponding to the actual part. It is listing `A22NZ-*`, but the family is `A22NL`. Also I can't find the specific PN in the catalog ordering information.

Comment: Yeah thanks @Transistor (+1) - remember I'm a newb so from the device page (linked in the question above) I see a link for [Datasheets](https://industrial.omron.us/en/media/A22NS_A22NW_Datasheet_en_201507_A34I-E-01_tcm849-113129.pdf). Is that not correct?

Comment: @Smeeb.. the issue with your link is... in 6 months digikey may no longer carry that part so the link will be broken here. Use the direct link to the manufacturer instead.

Comment: Also it often helps if you list the exact part number here when the datasheet is for a family. We have no idea which particular variant especially LED voltage you have chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With switches look for the switches internal connection diagrams  that are usually included.

Here from [page 15](https://industrial.omron.us/en/media/A22NS_A22NW_Datasheet_en_201507_A34I-E-01_tcm849-113129.pdf) of your switch you linked..

[image]

Note the illumination is fully under your control.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor but what exact URL is that from?! I can't find it anywhere on the DigiKey page linked in my qestion!

Comment: @smeeb This is from the datasheet on the page you linked in your answer.  Page 15 on the bottom right.

Comment: @smeeb DIgikey always links to the actual **Datasheets** which is nice. Look at the link under documents and media in your linked page.

Comment: Ahh beautiful @Trevor thanks again! So, to understand this, I think I obviously want Lighted Switches (so the right-most diagram). But what do `1`, `2`, `X1`, `X2`, `X`, `3` and `4` all represent?

Comment: Pin numbers....

Comment: Thanks @EugeneSh. (+1) so please take a look at the left-most wiring column under the **Lighted Switches** section. It shows Pin 1 connected to Pin 2 with a weird x-like symbol in between them. I can't find this symbol on any wiring/schematic cheatsheets, any idea what that symbol is?

Comment: It's a normally-closed switch. The `X` in a circle is your lightbulb

Comment: Ahhh, I'm startin' to get I think... so am I reading that diagram correctly: connect Pin 1 to Pin 2, connect Pin X1 to X and X2, and leave Pin 3 and Pin 4 disconnected from each other?

Comment: @Smeeb, it depends on how you are wiring the thing to your circuit... IF you want  the normally open switch use pins 3&4, if you want normally closed use 1 & 2. Hook up X1 and X2 to the appropriate driver to illuminate the switch.

Comment: No, no, no. The diagram is of *internal* connections. Which are inside the switch. If you want it to close some circuit, when pushed, you connect that circuit on pins 3&4. If you want it to *disconnect* on push, you connect it to `1&2`. If you want it to light up, you connect voltage to X1&X2

Comment: No. For the normally closed contact, the switch connects pin 1 to pin 2 when the button is not pressed, and disconnects them when pressed.  You connect your wiring to pin 1 and pin 2.  For the light module you connect your lamp power and ground leads to terminals X1 and X2.  That switch family can be purchased as separate actuator button, NC switch, NO switch, and Lamp modules.